# In TFS Build (MSBuild), how can I only have a specifc project in my drop folder

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

"Out of the box" the build in TFS will compile a complete solution and put all the "deliverables" from all its project into the drop folder.

How can I have only the deliverables from a single "main" project end up in the drop folder, why still having all other projects (which it depends upon) compiled?

Comment: What would you want to happen to the other projects?  Surely, if your project depends on a dll, then the dll must be put into a location where is can be seen by your main project.

Comment: The "non-essential" deliverables from other projects should disappear into thin air :). Typically these are projects that are for non-automated tests or tools. Also, it would be useful to me to separate unit test project deliverables from production code. After all, when I deliver, I do not want the unit tests in the delivery.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if this is what you want, but try:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="c:\drop\myfile.dll"  DestinationFiles="c:\temp"  />
    <Delete Files="c:\drop\myfile.dll" />
</Target>
```

Basically, moving them away from the drop location after build.

Comment: Thanks. That's a promising direction. But that would require me to specify each and every file that I need to preserve. Isn't there some way for me to indicate the project I'm interested and have its products automagically preserved for me? :)

Comment: You can recursively copy files if that's what you mean: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2005/11/07/490068.aspx

Comment: Thanks again. I don't think recursion helps me. What I need is a filter - Something that will give me only those DLLs and files that come from the direct compilation of the "main" project. The non-essential deliverables from all other projects in the solution are cluttering my drop folder.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a separate Solutions for your projects.
So then you can control which project should go to Drop Folder in one of the solutions and those that do not in another solution

Comment: Not quite what I need. The projects are in the solution for a reason - the main project depends on them.